# The maximum number of threads in the thread pool is incorrect

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a thread pool with a maximum number of threads of 3. But only one thread is executed, what happened?

```
public class Volatile {

    private volatile static boolean keepA = true;
    private static boolean keepB = true;

    private static ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,
            3, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>() );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            while (keepA) {
                System.out.println("keepA running...");
            }
            System.out.println("keepA stop!!!!!!");
        });
        executor.execute(() -> {
            while (keepB) {
                System.out.println("keepB running...");
            }
            System.out.println("keepB stop!!!!!!");
        });
        executor.execute(() -> {
            keepA = false;
            keepB = false;
        });
        while (true) {

        }
    }
}
```

result

> keepA running...
>   keepA running...
>   keepA running...
>   ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-core threads will only be started when the queue is full (and you have an unbounded queue, so that never happens).

As [per Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks. The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing:
>
> - If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a new thread rather than queuing.
> - If corePoolSize or more threads are running, **the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread**.
> - If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

Comment: The next passage in the JavaDoc is also very relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the initial amount of threads running in parallel. You have set it to 1. Change it to 3 and try again. This size should grow only when the queue is full, but your queue is of infinite size and is never full.

> ```
> public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
>               int maximumPoolSize,
>               long keepAliveTime,
>               TimeUnit unit,
>               BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
> ```
>
> Creates a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the given initial parameters and default
>   rejected execution handler.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `corePoolSize` - the number of
>     threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle, unless
>     `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` is set
> - `maximumPoolSize` - the maximum number of
>     threads to allow in the pool
> - `keepAliveTime` - when the number of
>     threads is greater than the core, this is the maximum time that excess
>     idle threads will wait for new tasks before terminating.
> - `unit` - the
>     time unit for the `keepAliveTime` argument
> - `workQueue` - the queue to use
>     for holding tasks before they are executed. This queue will hold only
>     the Runnable tasks submitted by the execute method.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - `IllegalArgumentException` - if one of the following holds:
>
>   ```
>   `corePoolSize < 0`
>   `keepAliveTime < 0`
>   `maximumPoolSize <= 0`
>   `maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize`
>   ```
> - `NullPointerException` - if `workQueue` or `threadFactory` is
>     `null`

Comment: _"The first parameter to ThreadPoolExecutor is the amount of threads running in parallel."_ - No it's not. At least not exactly.

Comment: Edited to "initial amount". Thanks!